# Need Help Converting Batch to Shell

Tags: java, shell, batch-file, ssl, vps

I've looked all over for the past few days and tried MANY different things but just can't seem to convert my batch file to a shell file to run a maplestory private server on a linux VPS

my batch file is...

```
@echo off
@title TiredStory World Server
set CLASSPATH=.;dist\TiredStory.jar;dist\mina-core.jar;dist\slf4j-api.jar;dist\slf4j-       jdk14.jar;dist\mysql-connector-java-bin.jar
java -Xmx100m -Dwzpath=wz\ 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=filename.keystore 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keoki 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=filename.keystore 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=passwd 
-Drecvops=recvops.properties 
-Dsendops=sendops.properties 
net.world.WorldServer
pause
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you tried and it's not working?

Comment: Where is your shell program?  What happens when you run it?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't need '@echo off' nor '@title' nor 'pause', so your shell script would be reduced to this:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:dist/TiredStory.jar:dist/mina-core.jar:dist/slf4j-api.jar:dist/slf4j-jdk14.jar:dist/mysql-connector-java-bin.jar
java -Xmx100m -Dwzpath=wz \ 
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=filename.keystore \
    -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keoki \
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=filename.keystore \
    -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=passwd \
    -Drecvops=recvops.properties \
    -Dsendops=sendops.properties \
    net.world.WorldServer
```

- '@echo off' is just to deactivate the echo, no functional effect in your case
- '@title' is just to set the title in the window of your command line in windows, no use in a shell
- in the classpath replace ';' with ':'
- instead of "set": "export" (although export is in case you have subshells, it doesn't harm anyway if you have it)
- when you break a line, use `\` every time you do it
- pause is just to (obviously) make a pause, no functional inpact in your case

Comment: Classpath directory separator should be "/" (for unix) **not** "\" (which is for windows).

Comment: @DavidPostill the script is meant to run in a LINUX environment, Did you even read the question?

Comment: Yes I did. In your answer you correctly said "in the classpath replace ';' with ':'" but you didn't change the "\" for "/" in the classpath which needs to be done as well "export CLASSPATH=.:dist/TiredStory.jar:dist/mina-core.jar:dist/slf4j-api.jar:dist/slf4j-jdk14.jar:dist/mysql-connector-java-bin.jar"

Comment: @DavidPostill sorry, my fault, I thought you were refering to the line breaks

Answer (score 0):

Here's my translation:

```
#! /bin/bash

export CLASSPATH="."
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:dist/TiredStory.jar"
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:dist/mina-core.jar"
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:dist/slf4j-api.jar"
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:dist/slf4j-jdk14.jar"
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:dist/mysql-connector-java-bin.jar"

java -Xmx100m -Dwzpath=wz \ 
  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=filename.keystore \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=keoki \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=filename.keystore \
  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=passwd \
  -Drecvops=recvops.properties \
  -Dsendops=sendops.properties \
  net.world.WorldServer
```

Note the `CLASSPATH` entries are relative directories, which is usually a Bad Idea.  Also, I wasn't sure what value you needed the `wzpath` attribute to be (was it supposed to include a space or back slash?) Here it is merely `wz`.